# Etymologie: Läuft bei dir

Tags: etymology

`Läuft bei dir` [wurde wie bekannt](http://www.wissen.de/das-jugendwort-2014-laeuft-bei-dir) zum Jugendwort 2014 gewählt. Was ist die Herkunft dieses Ausdrucks? Lässt sich diese Redewendung ähnlich wie [`Babo`] (Boss oder Anführer) zurückverfolgen?

> Bei "Babo" zumindest ist die Sache klar: Das Wort stammt aus dem Song "Chabos wissen, wer der Babo ist" des deutsch-türkischen Rappers Haftbefehl.

[Spiegel](http://spiegel.de/schulspiegel/a-935468.html)

Comment: Es ist kurz für "Es läuft bei dir" und basiert einfach auf der Bedeutung von "laufen" als "gut laufen/nach Plan laufen". Daher glaube ich kaum, dass sich zurückverfolgen lässt wo es herkommt. Zumal "Läuft" auf Antwort für "Wie geht's" auch ältere Leute sagen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Ausdruck kommt von "Es läuft gut", was z. B. als eine Antwort auf "Wie geht es dir?" gegeben werden kann.
Der häufigste Sprachgebrauch für die Frage "Wie läuft's?" und die Antwort "Läuft gut." ist meiner Meinung nach bei Projekten. Wenn mein Chef fragen will, wie es mir zurzeit mit meinem Projekt geht, fragt er mich "Wie läuft's (mit deinem Projekt)?"
Diese Phrasen verwenden aber nicht nur Jugendliche (wie gesagt, auch mein Chef verwendet sie).

Das Jugendwort "läuft bei dir" wird wie ein Kompliment verwendet. Damit wird Anerkennung ausgedrückt, weil beim Gesprächspartner wohl "alles gut ist".